# vs code shortcut or plugin in add import statement

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there a shortcut or plugin in add an import statement like

`import { ApolloClient } from 'apollo-client'`

I'm sure I used to do it by pressing `i` space and then Tab which gave me

`import {} from ''`

the cursor would then jump to the from statement and then Tab would take me to the `{}`

Comment: That still works for me.  OS? Filetype? If you scroll down in the suggestions pop-up do you see `import statement` as an option?  Maybe it just got buried down a ways.

Comment: OS - macOS Catalina, filetype - tsx, do I search for suggestions pop-up in the preferences > settings ? In there I don't have `import statement`

Comment: I tested in `tsx` file and it works fine.  You should be able to just type the `i` and a suggestion box pops up and `import statement` is one of the options.  What is your `Editor: Quick Suggestions` setting set to?  Also, put `Editor: Snippet Suggestions` to `top`.

Comment: And is the language identified as `Typescript React` in the lower right corner?  And if you do ` tsc -v` in the terminal what version of typescript is reported?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add any shortcut you want to in VSCode via the **`keybindings.json`** file.

1. Press F1
2. When the input drops open type: "**Open Keyboard Shortcuts**" -  It will have "(JSON)" next to it. Select the `Open Keyboard Shortcuts (json)` option when you see it.
3. You should be in a JSON file. Now follow the instructions in the snippet below.

```
    // Inside the JSON files Curly Brackets, copy and paste the block below
    {
        // Follow the comment instructions
        {
            "key": "CTRL+SHIFT+I", // Choose the keybinding you want to use.
            "command": "type", // You will use 'type' for the command to exec
            "args": {
            "text": "import {} from ''" // enter the string that you want to auto-type
            }
        },
    },

    /* 
         If you did everything correctly you should be able to use the 
         keybinding you choose to have it auto type your text argument*/
```

[For more help visit this **Official VSCode Guide**: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the extension [My Code Actions](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.my-code-actions)

You can define the action to be always available to include:

```
"my-code-actions.actions": {
    "[javascript]": {
      "import ApolloClient": {
        //"diagnostics": ["\"(.*?)\" is not defined"],
        "text": "import { ApolloClient } from 'apollo-client'\n",
        "where": "afterLast",
        "insertFind": "^(import |from \\w+ import )"
      }
    }
  }
```

If this is related to an entry in the PROBLEMS panel (red squigle) you can add the `"diagnostics"` property.